# How to mock a constructor which is throwing a IOException with mockito-inline?

Tags: exception, constructor, mocking, mockito-inline

How can i mock the next lines:

```
Workbook templateWorkBook = null;
try {
  templateWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(templateWithoutEvents);
} catch (IOException ex){
  log.error("Error creating workbook from file");
}
```

I was trying somethig like this but doesn't work.

```
try (
                MockedConstruction<XSSFWorkbook> mocked = Mockito.mockConstructionWithAnswer(XSSFWorkbook.class, invocation -> null)
                ) {
            doReturn("2021-09-30").when(stpConfigurationMock).getStartDate();
            **when(new XSSFWorkbook()).thenThrow(IOException.class);**
            Workbook workBook = fileService.generateReport(listItem, startDate, endDate);
        }
```

I have the exception when run tests:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
```

Any ideea? Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to find a solution to this problem myself, and using this solution works for my case :

```java
try (MockedConstruction<XSSFWorkbook> mocked = 
Mockito.mockConstructionWithAnswer(XSSFWorkbook.class, invocation -> {
    throw new IOException();
})) {
    Workbook workBook = fileService.generateReport(listItem, startDate, endDate);
}
```

the constructor itself is not mocked by MockedConstruction, but intercepted. Which explains the error you are getting

Comment: I tried this and it works

Comment: The Answer is executed on method invocation of the mock, not on construction.  So this doesn't work as expected.  The IOException will be thrown the first time the object is accessed, not when constructed.