# How to migrate PowerMockito whenNew thenThrow to Mockito Inline MockedConstruction

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, powermockito

We're migrating all our code away from PowerMock to Mockito Inline, I've mostly been able to migrate all cases but I don't know how to throw an exception when an instance of a specific class is created, using Mockito MockedConstruction.

i.e I need to migrate to Mockito Inline from this:

```
whenNew(MyClass.class).withAnyArguments().thenThrow(new MyException("fail"));
```

I've read the docs and I can't find how to do it.

I've tried this:

```
try (MockedConstruction<MyClass> ignored = mockConstruction(MyClass.class, 
         (mock, context) -> { when(new MyClass(any())).thenThrow(new MyException("fail"));})
) {
      stuffToTest();
  }
```

I've also tried the suggested solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70122376/how-to-mock-a-constructor-which-is-throwing-a-ioexception-with-mockito-inline) but it doesn't work.

Comment: What code are you trying to test? How is the constructed object used in `stuffToTest` method?

Comment: It's not really relevant -the important thing is that it constructs an instance of MyClass and that the constructor should throw an exception when called.
This is possible with PowerMock but I can't find a way to do it with Mockito Inline, which is supposed to be a newer and nicer alternative

Comment: It is relevant because of how `mockito-inline` works and how it handles mocking static methods and objects construction. It is not just a copy of the way PowerMock work(ed).

Comment: Then let's just say I'm trying to test
void stuffToTest() { new MyClass("hello"); }

Comment: Curious if you found an answer.  The linked solution doesn't work as the "Answer" is not executed on construction but on method invocations on the mock.  I am starting to suspect this isn't possible.